# Merging two DEMs in different pixel bits?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst

I have 2 different Digital Elevation Modeling (DEM). One is the state DEM and has 30m and has 16 pixel bit. I have a couple of smaller DEM that has 30m but they have 32 pixel bit.

I know how to merge them, but in my mind, do the Pixel bits have to be in the same pixel bits for example, 30m 16 pixel bits equal to 30m 16 pixel bits, correct ?

Reason for asking this question was because when I am working on a watershed and clipped state 30m 16 bit in half and the other smaller DEM has 30m 32 bits and merge them.

I tried to find this on the internet and found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signed 16 bit integers range from -32,768 to 32,767, unsigned from 0 to 65,535. As your DEM values are very unlikely to be outside that range, it won't be a problem if you merge with a 32 bit integer/floating point raster. Though you may want to ensure the output is 16 bit integer to reduce file size.